# yo jhipster : Failed to connect to "git://github.com"

Tags: git, github, yeoman, jhipster

I'm trying to create a new project using JHipster (and windows 10) but I get this warning message :

```
WARNING! Failed to connect to "git://github.com"
```

The rest of the creation goes smoothly but later the project doesn't work because it misses components from github.

I configured my proxy and the next line works

```
git ls-remote http://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of research I discovered rff-doctor (https://github.com/rakuten-frontend/rff-doctor) and diagnosed this :

```
× Failed to connect to "git://github.com".
 Error: Command failed: git ls-remote git://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git HEAD
 1. Check the Internet connection.
 2. If you are using HTTP proxy, try this command:
      $ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

I ran the command and the next connections worked.

Comment: Outstanding!! Saved my day! By the way, in certain environments, one might also need to `git config http.proxy <proxy-URL>`

Comment: damn, I was too early optimistic. For some weird reason, rff-doctor still reports "Failed to connect to git://github.com", even though running `git ls-remote git://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git` in the same terminal window gives me `d0dd1f61b33d64e29d8bc1372a94ef6a2fee76a9        HEAD`. Running `jhipster` also gives the same error. Any ideas how to resolve it ?

Comment: that was due to long response time via proxy. see also here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7977#issuecomment-405220534